# Disable "Open in Excel" in Excel Services on SharePoint 2010

Tags: excel-services, office-web-apps

I would like to disable or remove the ability for users to use the "Open in Excel" button and only allow the "Edit in Browser" button.

Can this be done through security settings and/or user groups? Ideally, I'd like to be able to specify who can use the "Open in Excel" button and for everyone else to "Edit in Browser" only.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no configuration option to make this happen.  In addition, the Office Web Apps use their own master pages, so editing the master page of your SharePoint site wouldn't even give you the option to do it on the client side.

Comment: Thanks! That's too bad for me, but I'll work around it.

Comment: hiding it by css possible with display:none, it is worked for me but if we can defined it by permission level. Those who Contributers with open in excel and those who haven't any privilege to open or download in client but can edit in web app.

Answer (score 0):

Office web app uses minimal.master relative to the site you open a document in. this post will helps you regarding your question : http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/e2ee8c6a-f9f7-43d3-bf52-759669a85cfd/